# Where is this error coming from

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash

I work for a video hosting and delivery company. We supply our clients an iframe to embed our player (Flash or HTML5 based on detection) in their sites.

I have a customer with issues and I can not get to the bottom of an issue he is having. When his browser (Chrome/FF/IE) renders this page:

I sometimes see this error (which is not from us) in place of our player: 
[image]

The misspelling leads me to wonder if he has some malware is preventing our Flash player from loading. The attempts to load the player all fail with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhat of an unusual question considering it is not you who is having the problem. Do you have access to the client's computer? If not, it is going to be difficult to help resolve this. Do you know if they have run virus and malware scans?

Comment: Since Flash V11.2 r202, machines with older CPU's (that lack a security feature SSE2) will fail to load flash. When a browser tries to load flash in this situation, it brings up some image (sorry, forgot how generic that image is). Could someone have replaced that error image with this one attempting to tell them about it? A long way to get to - What does this customer have for a CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Nice find with the mis-spelling in the error message. Mis-spellings are a good indicator to a possible virus, adware or malware and I have seen this is on a number of occasions.

From my own experience there are several things you can try. You can check the list of installed programs for anything unusual. You can check the list of add-ons listed in IE options for anything suspicious there.

You can use Sysinternals' Process Explorer to see if there are any suspicious child processes running under IE/FF/Chrome. If you haven't heard of this tool it's essentially a souped-up version of Task Manager.

You can also use Sysinternals' Autoruns to check for any suspicious modifications to the operating system's auto-start points. If you haven't heard of this tool it's essentially a souped-up version of msconfig's Startup tab. I suspect an autostart point may have been modified to allow the malware to startup automatically so Autoruns should help you find this. Whilst you are there, worth it If you check the Internet Explorer tab to check for anything suspicious.

Both the above tools you can find on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/SysInternals.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I can access the client's computer but have to do it via an (e.g. TeamViewer) screen-sharing session. The client is not very computer literate - simply getting TeamViewer installed so I could see his machine took a call well over an hour yesterday. He doesn't understand basic concepts like files and folders, add-ons, etc. But, I now have TeamViewer installed so I can schedule future sessions more easily.